# Zookeeper's zoo.cfg not exists

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to install zookeeper 3.6. 
in this tutorial:
http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/11/InstallingAndConfiguringStormOnUbuntu.html
mentioned that I have to set some configurations in zoo.cfg file but there is no zoo.cfg at all. What should I do?
I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 desktop
These are the files in my zookeeper's conf directory:
configuration.xsl
log4j.properties
zoo_sample.cfg
What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

There is should be a zoo_sample.cfg in the package. copy that zoo.cfg and make the changes you may need